# Irreducible polynomial must be constant

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assuming that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $F[x]$ are both irreducible. They are in a principal ideal, generated by some $q(x)\in F [x]$. I have in the text that:

$f = qf_1$ and $g = qg_1$ which somehow implies that $f_1$ and $g_1$ are constant polynomials

This is the main focus of the proof, but I don't understand this step.

.

For context: I am attempting to prove that two polynomials in a field with different degrees and the ideal is not equal to the field implies that they can't both be irreducible.

Comment: I'd rather conclude that $f_1,g_1$ are constants

Comment: I'm assuming you're told that $q$ is nonconstant and then you want to conclude $f_1$ and $g_1$ are constant, not $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ assumed to be distinct? Is $q$ nonconstant?

Comment: If $f_1$ is a nonunit then  $\,f = qf_1$ is a product of (nonzero) nonunits, contra $f$ is irreducible. Same for $g_1.\ \ $

Comment: Sorry, yes. It has been edited.

Answer (score -2):

Since f and g both are irreducible in F.
so if we suppose that these polynomials are non constant they become a multiple of q but in the very first place these polynomials were irreducible in F here we get the contradiction so these polynomials are constant. 
That's what I think!

Comment: Please see the comments under the OP. The original question is poorly stated, because (if the question wasn't mis-stated) it's $f_1$ and $g_1$ that must be constant, not $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I interpreted the answer as referring to $f_1$ and $g_1$ when saying 'these polynomials' and then the argument is perfectly fine.